# How to get full html body of google search using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a following problem. I would like to get full HTML body of google search output.

Suppose, I would like to google `Everton stadium address`. This is my python code:

```py
import urllib.request as urllib2

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'

url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=Everton+stadium+address"
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,}

request=urllib2.Request(url,None,headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
```

But when I print my `data` I can see that the html of the right part of the page is missing, see the missing red area:

[image]

how can I get full html body including the red part, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.google.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'de,de-DE;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,fr;q=0.5,de-CH;q=0.4,es;q=0.3',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'dnt': '1',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
    'sec-ch-ua-arch': '"x86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-bitness': '"64"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version': '"109.0.1518.78"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version-list': '"Not_A Brand";v="99.0.0.0", "Microsoft Edge";v="109.0.1518.78", "Chromium";v="109.0.5414.120"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-model': '""',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"10.0.0"',
    'sec-ch-ua-wow64': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/109.0.1518.78',
}

params = {
    'q': 'Everton stadium address',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', params=params, headers=headers)
print(response.content)
```

request serves me the full html, including the section you mentioned.